# Web application access permission

Tags: sql-server, http, port, tcpip

I have a web application that uses  SQL server .

SQL server is hosted on a server and accessed using port 1433 .

My question is will the user who is accessing my application required to be able to establish the communication with the port 1433 .

As far as i know, the user will be opening the application login page using port 80 . And will need to enter his credentials on the login page and click submit . As credentials are stored in the SQLSERVER database i do not know who will open the port 1433 is it the application itself or it is the user in order to check if the credentials exit or not .

Any clarification would help.

Comment: It ismple as it is, if you don't give access to a specific port at network level, which can be restricted to IP or subnet then they have no way to access to it. They can't even get login prompt if the login page is also accessible only on port 1443. It is not clear what you are asking exactly, so pls be more specific.

Comment: I have added more clarification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your server that runs your website needs to have access to port 1433. The users that are accessing your application via the web do not need access to port 1433. These users communicate with our webserver over port 80. And your webserver in turn, communicates with your database server over port 1433.

If your webserver and database server are hosted in the same data center and on the same network,  you may not even have to configure anything.

Comment: Thank you Olivier for your explanations .  The app server and database server are hosted on  the same server . The problem users arround the world accessing it will they need to be able to open port 1433 ? I am sure they need to be able to open the port 80  (outbound ) .

Comment: They would not need to open it.